# Probability of an event X given a previous event Y occurred assuming there is a probability of both X and Y occuring.

Tags: probability

Say for example:

25 people went on holiday. 12 flew to Asia, 9 flew to Europe and 5 have flew to both. A person is selected at random. If they visited Asia, then what's the probability that they've visited Europe?

How do you do this when you know that a certain number have done both?

Comment: How many went to Asia? How many went to both? Of those who went to Asia, what proportion went to both?

Comment: By definition, $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is

$$P(E|A)=\frac{P(E\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{5}{12}$$

Note that in conditional probability, the sample space is reduced once the knowledge of occurrence/non-occurrence of an event is gained.